# git remote url automatically resets

Tags: git, github, ssh, atom-editor

I want to push and pull to my GitHub repositories from inside Atom with the [git-plus package](https://atom.io/packages/git-plus).

I'm using Windows 10. Git is in my path. Github Desktop for Windows client works. Git Bash also works using remote https urls. In Atom using git-plus, I can add, commit, status, etc. **However**, when I attempt to push I kept getting this [error](https://github.com/akonwi/git-plus/issues/336) (which is in itself unimportant). Suffice to say that Atom requires GitHub authentication in order to use git-plus.

Several solutions online recommend using ssh (instead of https), but last time I did this it broke git entirely. (Perhaps I did it incorrectly.) Sticking to https, some solutions recommended using your password like so:

> https://{password}@github.com/user/repo.git

This is not at all secure, so I found a temporary solution in making an OAuth token and setting a given repository's remote url accordingly:

> https://{token}@github.com/user/repo.git

This worked at first, but **the remote url keeps resetting!**

Some repos reset to the ssh (`git@github.com/user/repo.git`) and some reset to https (`https://github.com/user/repo.git`). It also has to be set manually for each and every repository, which makes me think there is some other solution.

**My questions:**

What could be resetting the remote url?

Can I use ssh for some repos without bricking the rest?

Is there some global, more permanent way of associating the OAuth token with *every* remote repo?

Can I use `credential.helper` for this token? Or could I use `credential.cache` for my GitHub password in such a way that git-plus in Atom could still access?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and set the remote url to:

```
https://{user}@github.com/{user}/repo.git
```

(replacing `{user}` with your GitHub account username.)

That would allow git-plus to detect the username properly, asking you for the password.